# Color squares of a grid according to labels

Tags: r, matrix, visualization, grid-layout

I have created a 100x100 grid using the following code:

```
nb=100
nb1=nb
nb2=nb
minlat=45.18306
maxlat=45.6325
binlat=seq(minlat-0.05, maxlat+0.05, length.out = nb1)
minlon=8.724444
maxlon=9.519722
binlon=seq(minlon-0.05, maxlon+0.05, length.out = nb2)
```

And my data is grouped like follows:

```
n = 100
coord = matrix(0, n, 2)
coord[,1]= runif(100, min=45.18306, max=45.6325)
coord[,2]= runif(100, min=8.724444, max=9.519722)

lab=matrix(0, n, 1)
m=1
for(i in 1:nb1){
  for(j in 1:nb2){
    lab[coord[,1]>binlat[i] & coord[,1]<=binlat[i+1] & coord[,2]>binlon[j] & coord[,2]<=binlon[j+1]]=m
    m=m+1
  }
}
```

Assuming I have a matrix like the following:

```
a <- c(1000,2536,3045,6654)
b <- c(1,1,2,3)
matrix <- cbind(a,b)
```

where `a` is the vector identifying the grid square ID and `b` is the vector of the group to which the square belongs.

Is it possible to visualize the grid with the squares in `a` colored according to the group they belong to?
All the squares not included in `a` must be non-colored/white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid` to get a data frame of all the unique x and y values making up a grid.

```r
df <- expand.grid(x = binlon, y = binlat)
```

This will give you all the x values at each y value in order:

```r
head(df)
#>          x        y
#> 1 8.674444 45.13306
#> 2 8.683487 45.13306
#> 3 8.692530 45.13306 
#> 4 8.701574 45.13306
#> 5 8.710617 45.13306
#> 6 8.719660 45.13306
```

...and so on for 10,000 rows.

If your `a` column represents the matrix position of a cell with this ordering, then you can label the correct cell with a group by doing:

```r
df$group <- NA_real_
df$group[matrix[,'a']] <- matrix[,'b']
df$group <- factor(df$group)
```

(if this is transposed from what you intended, simply reverse the order of the arguments in `expand.grid`)

Plotting the result is probably easiest using `ggplot`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = group)) + 
  geom_tile(colour = 'gray90') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Set1', na.value = 'white')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still, I have a problem due to the fact that  (in my real case) only 625 of my squares are labeled while the rest dont have any label. Hence, ```df$group[matrix[,'a']] <- matrix[,'b']``` doesn't work for me as it expects the vectors of the matrix to be of length 10000.

Comment: @GiovanniIsgreeen no it doesn't. Here, only 4 of the squares are labelled out of 10,000 and the rest are `NA` . The expression `df$group[matrix[,'a']] <- matrix[,'b']` is writing four values in to the 10,000-length group column. The matrix can be whatever length you like.

Comment: @GiovanniIsgreeen that suggests that for some reason your `matrix` has 10625 rows, not 625 rows. Try `nrow(matrix)` to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks I have solved my problem. It was caused by the fect that in my real case ```a```was  a vector of characters and not numbers.